# XNA/MonoGame Tower Defense shoot projectiles from a tower?

Tags: c#, xna

I have the following method:

```
private void TryShoot(Tower t)
{
    double x1 = (GameMap.GetMapSquare(t).X * TILE_SIZE) + (TILE_SIZE / 4); // center location of square
    double y1 = (GameMap.GetMapSquare(t).Y * TILE_SIZE) + (TILE_SIZE / 4);
    foreach (Monster m in GameWave.Sent)
    {
        double x2 = GameMap.Path[m.PathLocation].X * TILE_SIZE + (TILE_SIZE / 4); // center location of monster
        double y2 = GameMap.Path[m.PathLocation].Y * TILE_SIZE + (TILE_SIZE / 4);
        double distance = Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow((x2 - x1), 2)) + (Math.Pow((y2 - y1), 2)));
        if (Math.Abs(distance) < t.Range)
        {
            // TODO: Shoot logic

            SpriteBatch.Draw(BulletTexture, new Rectangle((int)x1, (int)y1, 32, 32), Color.White);


            SpriteBatch.Draw(BulletTexture, new Rectangle((int)x1, (int)y1, 32, 32), Color.White);

            t.Shoot(m);
            if (m.Health <= 0)
            {
                Player.Gold += m.Worth;
                GameWave.Monsters.Remove(m);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Right after that TODO statement is where the shooting projectile logic should happen.
`x1` and `y1` is the location of the center square of the mapSquare object.

`x2` and `y2` is the location of the center square of the Enemy position on the mapSquare object.

This is a bird sprite being hit by a "bullet" that's being created at the tower, and also where that bullet is hitting.

[image: http://puu.sh/bcpxR.png]

It's ugly with a bunch of If else statements and while loops to do checking. There has to be a more efficient way of doing it, and if so, how?
I want to simulate a bullet moving from point A to point B (the while loop should work in theory but it's still just teleporting and not moving)

http://pastebin.com/4P05XgaD
(ugly code)

Thanks!

Comment: What is the specific problem? the bullet doesn't fire as you'd expect or it spawns in the wrong place? (your question should include the necessary code to reproduce it, without random links that some people tend not to click on)

Answer (score 1):

Do not mix update and draw functions. To fix your problem, you need 4 functions.

**Init Bullet** : simple function that will init  a bullet and add it to bullet list (start position, velocity, isEnemyBullet, bullet type...) this one is called single time, only when enemy or player shoot bullet.

**Update Bullet** : funciton that is called and loop over bullet list and increase position by velocity

**Draw Bullet** : function that loop over bullets and draw them.

**Collision Test**: function that loop over enemies and bullets and check collision